# Переход с одного UIViewController на другой, при помощи pushViewController или presentViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Доброй ночи всем, мне понадобился переход на другой ViewController через код, обычно я соединял button с UIViewController напрямую через Ctrl, (modal). Сейчас в программе открывается сначала проверка на соединение с интернетом и если все прошло ок, открывается основной UIViewController с программой. Но не тут то было, уже вторые сутки ищу как правильно поставить переход с одного на другой View. Единственное что попробовала куда-либо перейти это этот код:

```
import "ViewController"
...

ViewController *test = [[ViewController alloc] init];
       [self presentViewController:test animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Но открывал он черный фон, а не вьюшку.
Так же пробовал

```
ViewController *test = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:test animated:YES];
```

Ничего вообще не происходит, пробовал еще много разных способов, но эти были почти во всех статьях.
Помогите пожалуйста, в чем ошибка. Мне нужен вообще любой переход, без каких либо заморочек.
Заранее огромное вам спасибо.

Comment: Видимо уже все кто знают Objective-C легли спать, надеюсь завтра ответите)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы там случайно не со Storyboard работаете? Если да, то вам нужен другой способ инициализации вашего контроллера, чтобы брать его из storyboard:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil]; // Имя вашей storyboard, обычно так и есть - MainStoryboard.

ViewController *testViewController = (ViewController *)[storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"]; // identifier вам нужно, чтобы был проставлен в Storyboard.

NSLog(@"Проверяем, удалось ли получить контроллер: %@", testViewController);


[self.navigationController pushViewController:testViewController animated:YES];
```

P.S. Загадочна ваша формулировка вопроса - в нёй присутствуют конструкции, написанные лицами, как мужского, так и женского рода. И что это за времена такие, в которые мы живём? ;)

---

Вот так проставляется Identifier:

[image]

Comment: Пишу с кривого Safari, поставил модуль проверки орфографии) Теперь такая шляпа выходит) Спасибо большое за ответ, сейчас попробую)

Comment: http://f3.s.qip.ru/MQ9HpDCx.png
скриншот краша, что сделал не правильно? :C
А вот как проставил в Storyboard:
http://f4.s.qip.ru/MQ9HpDCy.png

Comment: Шляпа)) Нормально)) Я добавил ответ про краш - вы Identifier должны задать для контроллера, чтобы -[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:] знал, кого ему ловить ))

Comment: Сделал все как сказали и показали, теперь ошибок нет, лог приходит, http://f4.s.qip.ru/MQ9HpDCR.png , но переход не происходит, что-то не так?)) 

//А промо своей программы выдавать можно?) А то она у меня в топе Русского AppStore, 99р стоит, я б вам выдал за такую помощь :3

Comment: > А промо своей программы выдавать можно?)

Если хочется, можно до меня добраться через инфу в профиле, возражать не буду))

> но переход не происходит, что-то не так?)) 

А что происходит?

Comment: Беда, печаль происходит)) Ничего кроме лога не происходит, сейчас в скайпе заявку кину)

Comment: Напишите ещё вот так - 

    NSLog(@"Чтоб точно знать, что NavigationController есть: %@", self.navigationController);
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:testViewController animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**

Реализация без Segue.

Пишем в    `UIViewController`

```
static func storyboardInstance() -> VPTestViewController? {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VPTestViewController") as? VPTestViewController
    }
```

Далее там где необходимо вызвать контроллер пишем:

```
let testVC = VPTestViewController.storyboardInstance()
testVC.someText = "Test Text"
```

Далее как задумано логикой:

1) или через навигационный контроллер

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(testVC!, animated: true)
```

2) или модально

```
self.present(testVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Ну и не забываем конечно в нашем контроллере в сториборд указать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]