# Как ячейки из UITableView использовать для перехода на другой ViewController?

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, action, navigationcontroller

Есть NavigationController который через rootViewController подключен к ViewController.

В этом контроллере я создал TableView и через массив создал ячейки.

К сожалению не могу найти информацию, как сделать так, что бы при нажатии ячейки открывался новый ViewController.

Вся загвоздка в том, что все, что я находил в англоязычном интернете - это то, как через те же массивы сгенерировать определенную картинку с лейблом, а мне нужно подключить отдельные ViewController'ы.

Кто нибудь сталкивался с данной проблемой, или легче будет сделать меню через ScrollView?

*п.с. Пытался сделать отдельные прототипы ячеек и по одиночке их вписать в ViewController.swift, но тоже не сработало*

Создал отдельный View, создал swift файл TimeViewController и привязал его к виду в инспекторе.
В основном ViewController.swift я прописал функцию от **FreeGor**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако вылезла ошибка...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  let destination = TimeViewController()
  navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
}
```

Про переходы можно посмотреть: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/743918/14173

Answer (score 0):

Есть метод делегата UITableViewDelegate:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  .
  .
  .
  navigationController?.pushViewController(someViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Попробовал ваш совет. Дополнил вопрос

Comment: что такое TimeViewController? вы должны создать инстанс например так: let viewController = TimeViewController() и передать этот инстанс в метод push. Видимо вам нужно почитать и поделать побольше примеров.

Comment: TimeViewController это класс для окна приложения под названием "Time", которое должно открыться после нажатия ячейки "Время" в TableViewController. Вот и пытаюсь разобраться)

Answer (score 0):

Можешь в Storyboard это сделать.

Выбираешь в Cell в Storyboard(е) нажав и удерживая ctrl выбираешь тот контроллер на который хочешь перейти. Это самый простой способ реализации перехода с одного контроллера на другой. 
Если тебе нужно при этом передать информацию в тот контроллер куда ты переходишь. Тот вот один из вариантов: 
`let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Identifier") as! UIViewController
viewController.name = name
self.present(viewController, animated: true`

Comment: Ответ в текущем виде слишком неподробен и непонятен