# После загрузки progress bar не происходит переход в другой контроллер?

Tags: ios, swift, progress-bar

Не происходит переход после загрузки прогресс бара.Я понял так нужно сделать?Может кто нибудь подсказать что не так сделал.Уже и после скобок ставил переход, и оставил внутри таймер инвалайд, но тогда быстро идет переход , и не происходит загрузка.

```
import UIKit

class LauncViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var progressBar: UIProgressView!
    var progressValue = 0.0
    var timer: Timer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(updateProgressValue), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
              // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @objc func updateProgressValue() {
        progressValue = progressValue + 0.1
        self.progressBar.progress = Float(progressValue)

        if progressValue == 100 {

            timer.invalidate()
            let VC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LauncViewController") as!LoginController
            self.present(VC, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }


    }

    }
```

Comment: Посомотрите как сделать переход без Segue https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/266430/Переход-с-одного-uiviewcontroller-на-другой-при-помощи-pushviewcontroller-или-p/743918#743918

Comment: И нельзя Double и Float сравнивать на равенство явно, только с учетом точности. 
К примеру: if abs(progressValue - 100) < 1 { }
Просто сравнвая числа 100 и 100 вы можете сравнивать на самом деле 100.00001242 и 100.000002412 - а это уже разные числа.

Comment: Спасибо буду знать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина в том, что поле progress у UIProgressView изменяется от 0 до 1.
Что происходит в вашем коде: каждые 2 секунды прогресс-бар заполняется на 10% (0.1 / 1 = 10%), а вот значение progressValue дополняется только на 0.1% (0.1 / 100 = 0.1%). Соответственно, прогресс бар заполнится в сто раз быстрее, чем произойдет переход :)

Исправить это можно так:

```
progressValue >= 1
```