# Как перенести название ячейки в label

Tags: swift, uitableview, uilabel

Есть TableViewControlle с массивом ячеек, и есть другой ViewControlle c Label, нужно чтобы при нажатии на ячейку переходило в следующий ViewControlle и в Label отображало название ячейки по которой перешли.
Объясните как это можно сделать, заранее спасибо!

Comment: При переходе создается новый контроллер с Label? Или на время перехода контроллер уже существует?

Comment: Уже существует)

Comment: В storyboard существует ?

Comment: Да, существует )

Comment: Здесь описано как можно любой контроллер загрузить без segue: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/743918/14173

Answer (score 1):

У делегата `UITableView` есть метод

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Он отрабатывает при клике на ячейку. 
В этот момент вы может достать из вешего массива объект по `indexPath`

Тут же вы можете создать новый UIViewController, передать в него необходимые данные, после чего может совершить переход.

1. Если у вас есть `UINavigationController: self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)`
2. Если его нет: `self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

//Правка.

Если контролер уже существует и находится в `storyboard`. Его можно достать по storyboard ID.

`let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "someViewController")
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)`